# Query parameter or separate endpoint for returning the same resource in different formats?

Tags: http

So I've got this "resource", for want of a better word, that is returned by an endpoint:

```
GET /my/resource
```

Which is currently returned as JSON. This is synchronous, the call of the endpoint will fetch the data and then return it.

I'm creating a new endpoint, that returns the same resource as CSV. But not directly as CSV, but this will return a link to a file in a GCS bucket the client can download (I'm going to have to work out how to create signed URLs, but that's not relevant to this question).

But unlike the other endpoint, this is asynchronous. But this endpoint needs to take some time to create the CSV. So my plan was to return 202 Accepted until the endpoint actually creates the CSV, and then return a link to the CSV in a 200 OK.

So my questions are:

1. Is this approach a reasonable API design?
2. Should the second endpoint be `/my/resource/csv-link` or `/my/resource?format=csv-link`?

Regarding the second question, what leaned me towards  making this a query parameter was that it's essentially the same resource, just returned in a different format. But on the other hand, I feel like query parameters should change the data returned, but not the shape of the data. Like for these `/my/resource` endpoints I actually already have a bunch of query parameters that change the rows returned. But regardless of the query parameters the return type is an array of type Blah, formatted in JSON (is just has less rows in the array if query parameters filter it). Using the same endpoint in this case though would mean the same endpoint could return two different "types" (namely, JSON or link to a GCS bucket) depending on the input query parameters. And confuses things for autogenerated Typescript types from the OpenAPI spec I'm spitting out.

But again, it also feels weird having two different endpoints for essentially the same resource.

So which way should I be going here, or should I be doing something totally different?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `Accept` header for different formats of the same resource. If you alternatively want to provide a fallback using query parameters, you can do this but it's generally good to do the right thing first, before adding convenience workarounds.
2. I don't think `202 Accepted` is appropriate for a `GET` request like this. It makes a bit more sense I think to use (for example) a POST request to initiate the 'creation of the CSV export'. If you prefer `GET` have you considered just leaving the TCP connection open until the report is available? There's no real cost to this, and since your clients are presumably scripts they can just hang onto the connection until it's ready rather than occasionally check.

Also take a look at the `wait` and `respond-async` preferences in the `Prefer` header in this excellent RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240